# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions, Support Library v4 not wotking

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am writing an application in which I am using ExpandableList View as child of ViewPager page. This ViewPager_ExpandableList I update on some other event.

Basically On some event I am directly setting ViewPager to calculated page.
using `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);`

I checked with both solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22152267/2624806 and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7481468/2624806 solution but it;s not working. Also I have build-clean project but no luck.

Any suggestion.